# How do I figure out why my VBA Shell command is not working?

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is a Shell command in MS ACCESS VBA that is not working
(not getting an error message, but the code does not seem to be running)

```
        mycmd = "cmd.exe /c [" & StartFolder & "\mycommand.exe " & myfile & "]"
        Shell mycmd
```

The contents of mycmd seem fine
although there are some subfolders with multiple words in the folder name

any ideas?

was expecting the system to make a copy of an existing file.
no error msg but also the dos command did not execute

Comment: Any reason why you are not using [`FileCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filecopy-statement)? To see what your command does, launch a cmd.exe manually and paste the contents of mycmd into it.

Comment: @GSerg et al: ? How should `FileCopy` be able to execute `mycommand.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace those brackets with double-quotes:

```
mycmd = "cmd.exe /c """ & StartFolder & "\mycommand.exe " & myfile & """
```